# how to show div value using jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, html

i want to show my div value using jQuery. i have two div content values, the first one value is `subcategory value1` and the second one value is `subcategory value2`. So when i click button i want to show their corresponding value.

For example if i click second div button i want to show value `subcategory value2`.

Below i have mentioned the sample code for you:

```
    <div class='row'>
       <div class='form-group col-md-10'>
          <label>Sub Category Name:</label>
          <br />
          <input type='text' name='Sub_category1' id='Sub_category_id1' class='form-control' value="subcategory value1">
       </div>
       <div class='form-group col-md-2'>
          <br />
          <button type='button' id='showvalue' class='deleteupdateContact btn btn btn-danger btn-xs'>SHOW</button>
       </div>
     </div>
<div class='row'>
       <div class='form-group col-md-10'>
          <label>Sub Category Name:</label>
          <br />
          <input type='text' name='Sub_category2' id='Sub_category_id2' class='form-control' value="subcategory value2">
       </div>
       <div class='form-group col-md-2'>
          <br />
          <button type='button' id='showvalue' class='deleteupdateContact btn btn btn-danger btn-xs'>SHOW</button>
       </div>
     </div>
```

Please review this code.. provide me a best solution to this.. Thank you advance to every one..

Comment: First of, dont use id's with the same value, like `showvalue`, or `Sub_category_id1` use class insted

Comment: Ya Sure,, I will change the Sub_category_id1 to every one. but i want to show subcategory value..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use same id's in any case for more than one element of HTML.

```js
$('.showvalue').click(function(){
alert($(this).parent().parent('.row').find('input[type="text"]').val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='row'>
       <div class='form-group col-md-10'>
          <label>Sub Category Name:</label>
          <br />
          <input type='text' name='Sub_category1' id='Sub_category_id1' class='form-control' value="subcategory value1">
       </div>
       <div class='form-group col-md-2'>
          <br />
          <button type='button'  class='deleteupdateContact btn btn btn-danger btn-xs showvalue'>SHOW</button><!-- added showvalue as button class-->
       </div>
     </div>
<div class='row'>
       <div class='form-group col-md-10'>
          <label>Sub Category Name:</label>
          <br />
          <input type='text' name='Sub_category1' id='Sub_category_id1' class='form-control' value="subcategory value2">
       </div>
       <div class='form-group col-md-2'>
          <br />
          <button type='button' class='deleteupdateContact btn btn btn-danger btn-xs showvalue'>SHOW</button><!-- added showvalue as button class-->
       </div>
     </div>
```

Comment: @MuraliTharan  glad to help you:)